# Multiple Click function on Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-developer-toolbar

I am new to javascript and i m using this script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready
(function()
 {
     $('#apply').click(function()
     {
         $('#applyinfo').toggle("slow");
     });
 });
</script>
```

for the on click function when i click on apply it as to display the apply info div. this function is working however if i create multiple apply id it is not working. Please help me on this.

Comment: **`id`** should be unique, you should use **`class`** instead

Comment: Hi Pranav i am using 2 ids here which one i have use class

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to bind the click function for multiple dom elements you can use it as,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#apply,#apply1,#apply2').click(function() {
      $('#applyinfo').toggle("slow");
    });
  });
```

with `,` delimiter. However you cant name the same id's for various html elements. In that case go for a class selector as @Pranav suggested in comments

For ex,

```
  $('.applyClass').click(function() { .. } );
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` should be unique , so use common class to all those items

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.apply').click(function() {
    //-^-- class selector
      $('#applyinfo').toggle("slow");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id$='apply']").click(function() {
      $('#applyinfo').toggle("slow");
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

An `id` should be unique, so having multiple `#apply` and `#applyinfo` isn't a option. Instead, switch to classes.

The function depends on your HTML though.

If `.applyinfo` is a child of `.apply` this works:

HTML:

```
<div class="apply">Click here
  <div class="applyinfo">Toggle this info</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('.apply').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.applyinfo').toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.apply').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.applyinfo').toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="apply">Click here
  <div class="applyinfo">Toggle this info</div>
</div>

<div class="apply">Click here
  <div class="applyinfo">Toggle this info</div>
</div>

<div class="apply">Click here
  <div class="applyinfo">Toggle this info</div>
</div>
```

If the `.applyinfo` is not a child of `.apply` we need to find the matching div. The function then becomes:

HTML:

```
<a class="apply-1">Click</a>
<a class="apply-2">Click</a>
<a class="apply-3">Click</a>

<div class="applyinfo-1">Belongs to a.apply-1</div>
<div class="applyinfo-2">Belongs to a.apply-2</div>
<div class="applyinfo-3">Belongs to a.apply-3</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('[class^=apply-]').click(function() {
    var nr = $(this).attr('class').split("-").pop() ,
        selector = '.applyinfo-'+nr;
    $(selector).toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(function() {
  $('[class^=apply-]').click(function() {
    var nr = $(this).attr('class').split("-").pop() ,
        selector = '.applyinfo-'+nr;
    $(selector).toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="apply-1">Click</a>
<a class="apply-2">Click</a>
<a class="apply-3">Click</a>

<div class="applyinfo-1">Belongs to a.apply-1</div>
<div class="applyinfo-2">Belongs to a.apply-2</div>
<div class="applyinfo-3">Belongs to a.apply-3</div>
```